# Car (object) extraction from a image

Tags: image-processing, feature-extraction, background-subtraction

How will I proceed with the extraction of the whole car from an image containing a front, side or rear views, keeping in account of the shadows, other distant cars in the image and different types of cars (hatchback, sedan, etc.)?

The car in the image will be front, rear or either sides. That is fixed.
Car models can be different with varying colors and background.

I have researched on
- Edge Detection Algorithms ([Sobel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator), [Canny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector)),
reading about the [Scale-Invariant Feature Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) for Feature Extraction.

Am I going in the right direction ?

Sample Images :

[image]

[image]

Following results using Canny Edge Detection -

[image]

[image]

How to extract the car after the edge detection ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this paper [Mask R-CNN](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.06870.pdf) will also help you. If you want to be able of doing extraction of cars you have to train using a lot of training data of different cars, diferent angles, multiple cars in one picture.

Here and implementation using keras: [Mask RCNN](https://github.com/broadinstitute/keras-rcnn/tree/master/keras_rcnn)[image]